# I have to swap the values of two variables using a temporary variable

Tags: python

```
num1=input("Enter First Number = ")
num1=int(num1)
num2=input("Enter Second Number = ")
num2=int(num2)

temp=num1

num2=num1

temp=num2

 print("After Swapping, First Number - ", num1,"Second Number - ", num2)
```

This code not successfully shows the result. it shows some error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Just imagine trying to swap liquid between two cups using an empty third cup. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't list the error, but assuming you copy pasted, you have a space before your final `print`. That's an indention error.

As for swapping values, think about how you'd move items around.

You have

```
temp=num1
num2=num1
temp=num2
```

You are resetting `temp` twice. You never reset `num1`

Instead you can do this. Notice how both `num1` and `num2` get new values:

```
temp = num1
num1 = num2
num2 = temp
```

Even better, if you don't need that third variable is this:

```
num1, num2 = num2, num1
```